# Making Enemy Follow and Shoot Randomly at a multiple gameobjects with tags

Tags: unity-game-engine

Greeting, My friend and I have been trying to solve a problem of the Enemy script. The tags are "Player" the Enemy does not follow or shoot randomly, it only follows one and the rest it doesn't read the Tags of the other Game objects.

Thank you for your assistance

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class EnemyFollowPlayer : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float speed;
    public float lineOfSite;
    public float shootingRange;
    public float fireRate = 1f;

    private float nextFireTime;

    public GameObject bullet;
    public GameObject bulletParent;
    public GameObject[] player;

    private BlackthronpodPlayerX playerX;

    void Update () 
    {
        EnemyS ();
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player");

        playerX = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player").GetComponent<BlackthronpodPlayerX>(); 
    }

    void EnemyS () 
    {
        foreach (GameObject PlayerX in player) 
        {
            float distanceFromPlayer = Vector2.Distance (PlayerX.transform.position, transform.position);

            if (distanceFromPlayer < lineOfSite && distanceFromPlayer > shootingRange) 
            {
                transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards (this.transform.position, PlayerX.transform.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
            } 
            else if (distanceFromPlayer <= shootingRange && nextFireTime < Time.time) 
            {
                Instantiate (bullet, bulletParent.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

                nextFireTime = Time.time + fireRate;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: a bit unclear what you are trying to achieve .. should it follow the closest player? When should it change the target? currently you are kind of every frame move it towards any player inside the range .. so imagine your players equally spread around the enemy -> it will effectively never move since you would move it one step into each direction ..

Comment: Sorry about that.... I would want the Enemy to follow closest tagged object and shoot at nearest tagged object if the tagged object is out of LineOfSite. The Enemy only shoots at one Tagged object and never shoots. I also forgot to mention to that my enemy has an EnemyPatrol script it moves randomly in a fixed Surface Area. Sorry for the trouble...

Answer (score 0):

You say you want the closest player only so I would rather do something like e.g.

```c#
using System.Linq;

...

private bool TryGetClosestPlayer(out GameObject closest)
{
    // Sort the players by their distance to this object
    var playersSortedByDistance = player.OrderBy(p => ((Vector2)p.transform.position - (Vector2)transform.position).sqrMagnitude);
    // Get the first entry -> smallest distance
    closest = playersSortedByDistance.FirstOrDefault();

    // Returns true if a closest player was found
    // If this returns false it means there is no object tagged "Player" in your scene the moment "Start" was called
    return closest;
}

void EnemyS () 
{
    // Now only consider this one closest player and ignore the others
    if(TryGetClosestPlayer (out var closestPlayer))
    {
        var distanceFromPlayer = Vector2.Distance (closestPlayer.transform.position, transform.position);

        if (distanceFromPlayer < lineOfSite && distanceFromPlayer > shootingRange) 
        {
            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards (this.transform.position, PlayerX.transform.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        } 
        else if (distanceFromPlayer <= shootingRange && nextFireTime < Time.time) 
        {
            Instantiate (bullet, bulletParent.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

            nextFireTime = Time.time + fireRate;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Much Appreciated for your Help I'll look into it.

Comment: Sorry for asking..... But I'm not sure whether my Unity version is compatible it indicated an error on Reference of C#

Comment: Sorry for asking..... There was a reference error on C# version ( error CS1644: Feature `declaration expression' cannot be used because it is not part of the C# 4.0 language specification
) I think it might be the version I use for unity. My version is Unity 2017.3.1f1 with MonoDevelopement.

Comment: Oh yeah that's a bit older ^^ it probably refers to `out var closestPlayer` which is only possible since c# 7 afaik .. you can replace that by writing `GameObject closestPlayer = null; if(TryGetClosestPlayer (out closestPlayer)) ...`

Comment: There was a small problem on The Enemy it only shoots one player and never shoots again I I tried using this Script, so the player script is Decoy script for the player to destroy it.    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
If(collision.gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerDieEffect>() != null)
{ Destroy(collision.gameObject);
Destroy(gameObject);
}
}